# How to convert UTC time to local time

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new to programming.
How do I convert this `String` to local time in Swift?

```
var string = "7:55:26 PM"
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're goal is slightly unclear. Do you want to simply add or subtract a given value from the time, and still have it contained in a `String`?

Comment: what?? maybe "7:55:26 PM" is already local time? maybe it's UTC+8 time. Your question is like "how can I convert 100 money to dollars?"

Answer (score 0):

this is how you format the string in to NSDate , deploy the following code

```
 var dateFormat : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
     dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    var string = "2015-03-27 07:55:26"
     let date : NSDate = dateFormat.dateFromString(string)!
```